# How to disable auto-renaming in guake

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

I am using guake terminal, but its auto-renaming feature is annoying to me.
Can I have the same name for each tab, even when renaming it manually?

Answer (score 1):

just run

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/guake/general/use_vte_titles --type boolean false
```

and restart your terminal,

easy as pie(3.14)

If it does not work for you, try other [threads](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254566/annoying-autorenaming-in-guake)